# How to simply find matching values in [[], [], []] arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

new to javascript. i have these two arrays

```
var array1 = [['1'],['2']];
var array2 = [['2'],['3'],['4']];
```

how can i find the matching values?

tried below but returns empty array probably because it's for normal array structure ['', '', '']

```
var matchingValue = array1.filter(value => array2.includes(value));
Logger.log(matchingValue);
```

Matching value should be ['2']

Comment: What is `the matching values` here? Let me know the condition to say that is `match`.

Comment: hey @hong4rc should be 2

Comment: please add some more information: does the arrays contains only a single value? what happens if more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `.flat()` to flatten the arrays so you only deal with the values like so :-

```js
var array1 = [['1'],['2']];
var array2 = [['2'],['3'],['4']];

var matchingValue = array1.flat().filter((value) => array2.flat().includes(value) )
console.log(matchingValue);
```

Comment: brilliant. i never knew about flat before! thanks for the answer and introducing flat to me. appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

First, let's have a function that tells if two arrays are equal:

```
let equal = (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((_, i) => a[i] === b[i])
```

Then, use this function to find an intersection of two arrays:

```js
var array1 = [['1'],['2']];
var array2 = [['2'],['3'],['4']];

let equal = (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a.every((_, i) => a[i] === b[i])

result = array1.filter(x => array2.some(y => equal(x, y)))

console.log(result)
```

In a more generic way, you can write `intersectBy` that would compute an intersection using a predicate callback:

```
let intersectBy = (a, b, predicate) => 
   a.filter(x => b.some(y => predicate(x, y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.includes compares by identity, so it works with primitives and not with Array and Objects.

This is a solution that compares the first element of the internal arrays:

```
var matchingValue = array1.filter(value1 => {
  return array2.map(value2 => value2[0]).includes(value1[0]);
});
```

Array.map is used to convert an Array of Arrays in Array of strings, then Array.includes is used to match the first element of first Array.

This works only with the current structure (arrays of one element arrays).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [['1'],['2']];
const array2 = [['2'],['3'],['4']];

const array1Flat = [].concat(...array1);
const array2Flat = [].concat(...array2);

const matchingValue = array1Flat.filter((value) => array2Flat.includes(value));

console.log(matchingValue);
```

You don't need to use `.flat()` you can simply use concat and spread to flatten the array.

Comment: aa make sense. concat works great too. thanks :)